# Transitive models of ZF without Power Set

Tags: set-theory

I've read at different places that there are transitive classes that don't satisfy the power set axiom but I don't understand these classes look like. Is there a simple example?

It's easy to [break power-set if the class is not transitive](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/262721/233871) but if I'm not mistaken then a transitive class must satisfy axioms such as extensionality, empty-set, pair-set, union-set because ["the $\in$-relation of transitive models is the true $\in$ of the universe"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/312971/233871). Why can't I deduce the power set axiom using the same argument?

What kind of property beside transitivity would force power-set?

Comment: The powerset axiom is a $\Pi_2$ statement. So given some (class) model $N$ of $\operatorname{ZFC}$ and some $M$ satisfying $M \prec_{\Sigma_2} N$, we have that $M$ satisfies the powerset axiom. That's one way to "force" the powerset axiom.

Comment: Oh and btw: It is not true that every transitive model $M$ must satisfy pairing and union. For example $L_{\omega+1}$ is transitive but doesn't satisfy the pairing axiom. And [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00153-009-0163-1) is an example of a transitive model that doesn't satisfy union, but does satisfy all other axioms of $\operatorname{ZFC}$.

Comment: Oh okay, seems like I mixed that up, thanks for clarifying! Maybe for empty-set, pair-set, union-set it's sufficient to have a transitive model that is closed under these operations but for power-set it doesn't work this way? Does that make sense? See my comment on the answer below. Maybe I'm mixing things up again but I think I've read something like this, I'll check again.

Comment: Every nonempty transitive set contains the empty set as an element. And since "being the empty set" is $\Sigma_0$ definable, $M$ thinks that $x$ is the empty set iff $x$ is actually the empty set. If $M$ closed under the pairing function, then $M$ models the pairing axiom - if it is closed under unions, it models the union axiom. So you are right about these facts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the set of all hereditarily countable sets, then:

1. This set is transitive.
2. It satisfies extensionality, pairing, empty set, infinity subset schema and and replacement quite trivially. Even choice is easy here.
3. Less trivially, the axiom of union holds.
4. It does *not* satisfy the power set axiom.

More generally, if $\kappa$ is a regular, uncountable cardinal, then $H(\kappa)=\{x\mid|\operatorname{trcl}(x)|<\kappa\}$ is a transitive set satisfying all the axioms of $\sf ZFC$ except the power set axiom.

It follows that the power set axiom holds in $H(\kappa)$ if and only if $\kappa$ is a strong limit cardinal. But a regular strong limit is an inaccessible cardinal, and the existence of such cardinal cannot be proved within $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! One more thought: If a transitive class $M$ is closed under the power-set operation (ie $x\in M\implies \mathcal Px\in M$), does that imply the power-set axiom? Or is the axiom a stronger statement than just being closed under the corresponding operation?

Comment: @akkarin You actually need less: If $M$ is transitive, then $M \models \text{powerset}$ if and only if $\mathcal P(x) \cap M \in M$ for all $x \in M$. In particular, in a countable, transitive model of a sufficiently large fragment of $\operatorname{ZFC}$, there is some set $y$ of which $M$ thinks that it is the powerset of $\omega$. But $y = \mathcal P(\omega)\cap M$ is countable (in $V$).