Why Do we need Power Set Axiom in ZF even though I think we can define such set with previous axioms.
Let A={0,1}, by subset Axiom, we can say {0},{1},{0,1} are sets. By pairing axiom, { {0}, {0} } = {{0}} is a set. Similarly, {{1}}, {{0,1}} are sets. Then by empty set axiom, there exists a set ∅ and finally by union axiom we can have a set that contains ∅,{0},{1},{0,1} as elements which is the collection of all subsets of A. Is there any set that does not work this way?

How do you deal with an arbitrary set? How about an infinite set?

This might not be an answer to your question as stated, but consider https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1677596/87023

Try doing this for the set of natural numbers, and you’ll see what goes wrong.

You are not the first person to think this way. Even Russell himself thought that this axiom was dubious.
We need this axiom when dealing with infinite sets, as it is the only way to produce "bigger" sets. Without it, there is no way to prove the existence of an uncountable set. (e.g. the union of countably many countable sets is countable.)
Also, I'll leave this paper from arXiv titled What is the Theory ZFC Without Power Set?
